# Gluon Mobile : Bluetooth Low Energy, how to connect to a device with a given mac address after scanning?

Tags: gluon-mobile

I have a problem to connect to an arduino nano sense 33 BLE. The arduino module contains a profile which has a UUID.

Is it possible to connect to the arduino from the mac address to get profiles UUID then characteristics and finaly read the founded characteristics ?

This is how I proceed :

```
        BleDevice device = new BleDevice();
        device.setAddress("E4:38:4F:DA:9F:94"); // MAC ADDRESS of arduino
        BleService bleService = BleService.create().get();
        bleService.connect(device); // Connect to device
        List<BleProfile> list_of_profiles = device.getProfiles(); // Get list of profiles 

        for(BleProfile profile : list_of_profiles){
            System.out.println(profile.getUuid());// display uuid of profiles
            //Then get characteristics from profile
            //Then read characteristics
        }
```

**EDIT :**
Scan function updated : This is how I proceed for scanning devices :

```
public void scan_4_devices(){

        long t= System.currentTimeMillis();
        long end = t+5000;
        System.out.println("searching for devices ...");
        BleService.create().ifPresent(ble -> {
            ObservableList<BleDevice> ble_list_device = ble.startScanningDevices();
            System.out.println("SIZE BEFORE while loop : "+ble_list_device.size());
            ble_list_device.addListener((ListChangeListener<BleDevice>) c -> {
                while (c.next() && System.currentTimeMillis() < end ) {
                    System.out.println("SIZE IN while loop : "+ble_list_device.size());
                    if (c.wasAdded()) {
                        for (BleDevice device : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                            System.out.println("Device found: " + device.getName());
                        }
                    }
                }
                ble.stopScanningDevices();
            });
        });
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is a device search for 5 seconds, if the time is exceeded then I stop the device search. But the application keep crashing, this is the stacktrace after the crash.

```
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] V/GraalActivity(27191): Activity, get touch event, pcount = 1
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/GraalGluon(27191): Native Dalvik layer got touch event, pass to native Graal layer...
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/GraalGluon(27191): Native Dalvik layer got touch event, passed to native Graal layer...
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled(27191): traceEvent: Pushing TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=688,y=28]] to TouchPipeline[SmallMove]
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled(27191): traceEvent: Applying SmallMove to TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=688,y=28]]
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled(27191): traceEvent: Set TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=688,y=28]]
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled(27191): traceEvent: Set MouseState[x=688,y=28,wheel=0,buttonsPressed=IntSet[212]]
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled(27191): PPSRenderer: scenario.effect - createShader: Blend_SRC_IN
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] V/GraalActivity(27191): Activity, get touch event, pcount = 1
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/GraalGluon(27191): Native Dalvik layer got touch event, pass to native Graal layer...
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/GraalGluon(27191): Native Dalvik layer got touch event, passed to native Graal layer...
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] V/GraalActivity(27191): Activity, get touch event, pcount = 1
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/GraalGluon(27191): Native Dalvik layer got touch event, pass to native Graal layer...
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled(27191): don't add points, primary = -1
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/GraalGluon(27191): Native Dalvik layer got touch event, passed to native Graal layer...
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled(27191): traceEvent: Pushing TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=688,y=28]] to TouchPipeline[SmallMove]
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled(27191): traceEvent: Applying SmallMove to TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=688,y=28]]
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled(27191): traceEvent: Set TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=688,y=28]]
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled(27191): traceEvent: Pushing TouchState[0] to TouchPipeline[SmallMove]
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled(27191): traceEvent: Applying SmallMove to TouchState[0]
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled(27191): traceEvent: Set TouchState[0]
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled(27191): traceEvent: Set MouseState[x=688,y=28,wheel=0,buttonsPressed=IntSet[]]
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled(27191): searching for devices ...
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] I/GluonAttach(27191): JNI_OnLoad_ble called
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GluonAttach(27191): [BLESERVICE] Initializing native BLE from OnLoad
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalGluon(27191): ATTACH_DALVIK, tid = 27218, existed? 0, dalvikEnv at 0x7db4883200
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GluonAttach(27191): Util :: Load className com/gluonhq/helloandroid/DalvikBleService
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalGluon(27191): ATTACH_DALVIK, tid = 27218, existed? 1, dalvikEnv at 0x7db4883200
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] V/GluonAttach(27191): DalvikBle, init
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] V/GluonAttach(27191): Util <init>
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GluonAttach(27191): Calling Verify Permissions from Attach::Util
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] V/GraalActivity(27191): PermissionRequestActivity::Calling verifyPermissions
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] V/GraalActivity(27191): All requested permissions are granted
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GluonAttach(27191): Verify Permissions from native Attach::Util done
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalGluon(27191): DETACH_DALVIK, tid = 27218, existed = 1, env at 0x7db4883200
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GluonAttach(27191): Initializing native Ble done
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalGluon(27191): ATTACH_DALVIK, tid = 27218, existed? 1, dalvikEnv at 0x7db4883200
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] V/GluonAttach(27191): BLE startScanningPeripherals
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalGluon(27191): DETACH_DALVIK, tid = 27218, existed = 1, env at 0x7db4883200
[mar. mars 30 10:05:13 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] D/GraalCompiled(27191): SIZE BEFORE while loop : 0
[mar. mars 30 10:06:21 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] --------- beginning of crash
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867): ANR in com.hacare.ehacarebox (com.hacare.ehacarebox/com.gluonhq.helloandroid.MainActivity)
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867): PID: 27191
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867): Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 34.  Wait queue head age: 27397.5ms.)
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867): Load: 7.93 / 7.95 / 7.83
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867): CPU usage from 126795ms to 0ms ago (2021-03-30 10:04:15.526 to 2021-03-30 10:06:22.321):
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   11% 2867/system_server: 4% user + 7% kernel / faults: 21744 minor 78 major
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   4% 707/android.hardware.sensors@1.0-service: 1.3% user + 2.6% kernel / faults: 21 minor 5 major
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   2.4% 623/logd: 0.7% user + 1.7% kernel / faults: 539 minor 1 major
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   1.8% 23194/kworker/u16:11: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   2.1% 12638/com.android.bluetooth: 1.2% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 2319 minor 6 major
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   2% 3318/com.android.systemui: 1.5% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 7928 minor 376 major
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   1.7% 26869/kworker/u16:3: 0% user + 1.7% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   1.6% 23173/kworker/u16:9: 0% user + 1.6% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   1.3% 23196/kworker/u16:14: 0% user + 1.3% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.6% 24530/kworker/u16:0: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.9% 10811/com.sec.phone: 0.5% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 171 minor
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.8% 20538/kworker/u16:4: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.8% 732/surfaceflinger: 0.5% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 308 minor 16 major
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.6% 702/android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.1-service: 0.2% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 96 minor 2 major
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.5% 695/android.hardware.bluetooth@1.0-service-qti: 0.1% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 15 minor
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.4% 401/cfinteractive: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.3% 20184/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search: 0.3% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3639 minor 16 major
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.3% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.3% 80/smem_native_rpm: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.2% 13990/logcat: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 29 minor
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.1% 1//init: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 221 minor
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.1% 23078/mdss_fb0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.1% 29022/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 543 minor 1 major
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.1% 15/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.1% 29/ksoftirqd/3: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.1% 123/kswapd0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.1% 710/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 14 minor
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.1% 273/kgsl_worker_thr: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.1% 25576/kworker/0:1: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.1% 7/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.1% 3096/cds_mc_thread: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.1% 89/kcompactd0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.1% 26744/kworker/1:0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.1% 3307/com.sec.android.inputmethod: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 134 minor 5 major
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.1% 3927/iod: 0% user + 0% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.1% 10/rcuop/0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.1% 95/system: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0.1% 624/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 4 minor
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 26753/kworker/3:2: 0% user + 0% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 22/ksoftirqd/2: 0% user + 0% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 348/irq/305-fts_tou: 0% user + 0% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 25/rcuop/2: 0% user + 0% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 31420/adbd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 642 minor 2 major
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 701/android.hardware.graphics.allocator@2.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 57 minor
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 717/healthd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 4187/com.sec.android.app.launcher: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2727 minor 3 major
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 191/msm_serial_hs_0: 0% user + 0% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 2660/cnss-daemon: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 33 minor
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 20087/com.google.android.gms: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 875 minor
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 910/wlan_logging_th: 0% user + 0% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 27044/kworker/2:4: 0% user + 0% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 23224/com.android.vending: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 910 minor 3 major
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 18/rcuop/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 407/irq/181-spdm_bw: 0% user + 0% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 705/android.hardware.memtrack@1.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 12 minor
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 5231/com.samsung.cmh:CMH: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 207 minor 3 major
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 26472/com.google.android.apps.docs: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 57 minor
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 79/dsps_smem_glink: 0% user + 0% kernel
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/ActivityManager( 2867):   0% 83/msm_wa
[mar. mars 30 10:06:25 CEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] W/ActivityManager( 2867): anr : com.hacare.ehacarebox,0
```

As you can see the size of the list `ObservableList<BleDevice> ble_list_device = ble.startScanningDevices();` is 0. This may cause app crash

This is the main class source code:

```
package com.hacare;

import com.gluonhq.attach.util.Constants;
import com.hacare.views.PrimaryView;
import com.hacare.views.SecondaryView;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.Swatch;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class Main extends MobileApplication {

    public static final String PRIMARY_VIEW = HOME_VIEW;
    public static final String SECONDARY_VIEW = "test";
    
    @Override
    public void init() {
        addViewFactory(PRIMARY_VIEW, () -> new PrimaryView().getView());
        addViewFactory(SECONDARY_VIEW, () -> new SecondaryView().getView());
        DrawerManager.buildDrawer(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(Scene scene) {
        Swatch.BLUE.assignTo(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(Main.class.getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        ((Stage) scene.getWindow()).getIcons().add(new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/icon.png")));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty(Constants.ATTACH_DEBUG,"true");
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: how is this related to javafx?

Comment: I'm sorry I put the wrong tag, I will remove it @kleopatra

Comment: thanks for cleaning up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something have changed in the Android BLE Framework, for the moment the solution to fix this issue is to firstly change the attach version to 4.0.12-SNAPSHOT in pom.xml file.

`<attach.version>4.0.12-SNAPSHOT</attach.version>`

Then by adding the following repository :

`<repository>`
`<id>Snapshots</id>`
`<url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>`
`</repository>`

Thanks to [José Pereda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3956070/jos%c3%a9-pereda)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, once you connect you should wait for the connection status, before you start asking for the list of profiles.

These are some code snippets you could use:

Device discovery

```
BleService.create().ifPresent(ble -> {
    ObservableList<BleDevice> devices = ble.startScanningDevices();
    ...
    ble.stopScanningDevices();   
});
```

Device connect

```
BleService.create().ifPresent(ble -> {
    device.stateProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
        @Override
        public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
            if (State.STATE_CONNECTED.equals(device.getState())) {
                // device connected, get profiles:
                ObservableList<BleProfile> profiles = device.getProfiles();
                ...   
                device.stateProperty().removeListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
    ble.connect(device);
});
```

Profile characteristics

```
ObservableList<BleCharacteristic> characteristics = profile.getCharacteristics();
...
// read characteristic
BleService.create().ifPresent(ble -> 
    ble.readCharacteristic(device, profile.getUuid(), characteristic.getUuid());
// subscribe characteristic
BleService.create().ifPresent(ble -> 
    ble.subscribeCharacteristic(device, profile.getUuid(), characteristic.getUuid());

// write characteristic
BleService.create().ifPresent(ble -> 
    ble.writeCharacteristic(device, profile.getUuid(), characteristic.getUuid(), bytes));
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have edited the code snippet (device discovery) you provided me. The problem is that I have the feeling that my program does not stop when I do the device discovery by adding `devices.addListerner((ListChangeListener<BleDevice>) c -> ...`. Like in this example [device discovery snippet](https://docs.gluonhq.com/attach/javadoc/latest/com.gluonhq.attach.ble/com/gluonhq/attach/ble/BleService.html). Even if I add `ble.stopScanningDevices();` After the while loop my application still crashing. I also force my program to leave the while loop by adding a time limit.

Comment: If you have a crash, post the stacktrace, so we can see what is causing the error.

Comment: Can you run your app, while from a terminal you also run `adb logcat -v threadtime`? That will give you a more detailed stacktrace. Post a link to it? `adb` is under  Android sdk/platform-tools folder.

Comment: Here is a more detailed stacktrace [debug.txt](https://filebin.net/7yfz7tvrxs5po4cf/debug.txt?t=8sa58fs1)

Comment: If you check the debug file go to `03-30 11:38:22.300 30119 30119`. This is where there is the error `JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: GetStringUTFChars received NULL jstring`

Comment: Yes, issue code is [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/blob/master/modules/ble/src/main/native/android/dalvik/DalvikBleService.java#L440). Can you try again adding  `System.setProperty(Constant.ATTACH_DEBUG, "true");` to your main class and building again? That will give you more verbose output about the BLE service.

Comment: New link to debug file [debug.txt](https://filebin.net/2yrg40ofiy8gmp8p/debug.txt?t=efl2xp96) with `System.setProperty(Constants.ATTACH_DEBUG, "true");` added to main class

Comment: Did you build/package/install again the apk? I don't see debug info.

Comment: I compile/link/package/install. I will do it again like you said

Comment: Make sure debug is set early, like in your `main` method, before `launch(args)`.

Comment: My bad, I put it in the wrong place. Sorry for this inconveniance, here is the link to the new debug file  [debug.txt](https://gofile.io/d/gD5KQK)

Comment: I still don't see debug info. Are you sure you are using [this constant](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/blob/master/modules/util/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/attach/util/Constants.java#L37)?

Comment: Yes, in main class, main function before `launch(args)`

Comment: Can you post it? Something is wrong and it is not working

Comment: Here you go, I added it

Comment: Thanks, it looks good, so that should work and you should get more extensive logs with tag `GluonAttach`. Make sure you do.

Comment: Here is the new debug file with `GluonAttach` [debug.txt](https://filebin.net/bueuos7alrctpn91/debug.txt?t=tkgvfva5)

Comment: Even with another android device the application crashes. Something is wrong with the BLE. Can you try on your side and try to run the device discovery code as it exists in the [gluon mobile documentation](https://docs.gluonhq.com/attach/javadoc/latest/com.gluonhq.attach.ble/com/gluonhq/attach/ble/BleService.html)?

Comment: Version I'm using :
       `<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>`
        `<maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>`
        `<javafx.version>16</javafx.version>`
        `<charm.version>6.0.6</charm.version>`
        `<attach.version>4.0.11</attach.version>`
        `<client.plugin.version>0.1.38</client.plugin.version>`
        `<javafx.plugin.version>0.0.5</javafx.plugin.version>`

Comment: BLE device discovery works fine for me. Checking the logs, the problem might be in your Arduino, the BLE service doesn't include a name. Maybe there is a way to set it?

Comment: No there is no way to set a name. Did this may cause application crash ?

Comment: I tried without any BLE device around and the application keeps crashing. The arduino has nothing to do with it. I will delete my project and start again on good basis.

Comment: Same thing, I have the same issues when I created the project. This what I did after creating project : 

1) editing pom.xml : 
 - adding attach ble dependency 
 - adding ble to attachlist
2) I copy device discovery code snippet and import the needed libraries
3) build>package>install>run

I did not edit any AndroidManifest.xml file this time, and I still have the same issue as before. Even if I run it the stacktrace keep telling me that I have all required permission without editing AndroidManifest.xml
Is this strange to have permission of using bluetooth without editing manifest ?

Comment: Yes, the BLE service [sets](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/blob/master/modules/ble/src/main/resources/META-INF/substrate/dalvik/AndroidManifest.xml) those permissions.

Comment: I can reproduce your issue now. Something must have changed in the Android BLE framework. I have a possible fix, so it would be great if you can test this [apk](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l3fgnp2lfg3whs8/bledevices.apk?dl=0)?

Comment: It works! How did you manage to make it works ? Is there a way to get sources ? How did you fix it.

Comment: Ok, good to know. The fix is [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/commit/37ba17006108a629fb4970fa0a8b3ccd761f695d), and you can already test it by using Attach 4.0.12-SNAPSHOT, by adding this repository: `<repository>
    <id>Snapshots</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
</repository>`